# Lists as spans on .NET 6

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I know that if you want a fastest way to work with arrays, it recommends to change from:

```
var arr = new[]{
    100,101,102
};
```

to:

```
Span<int> arr = new[]{
    100,101,102
};
```

Looking on how lists are composed, we know that they have an array inside:

```
internal T[] _items;
```

But we don't have access to that.

How can i work the list as a span like:

```
Span<int> arr = new List<int>{
    100,101,102
}.AsSpan;
```

Is it possible to do it? In case of true, it provides an advantage / disadvantage? Could i access to the array inside the list?

If anyone can explain or develop the topic I would appreciate it.

Comment: It is possible but not advisable as lists don’t represent a single, fixed block of memory